# ActiveMQ + JBoss Fuse REST

Tags: rest, activemq-classic, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I'm trying to use JBoss Fuse activemq OSGi bundle. I'm able to produce and consume messages via standard JAVA JMS client, but I'm facing problem using REST API (HTTP)
for istance the curl method prosed by ActiveMQ documentation:

```
curl -u admin:admin -d "message" http://localhost:61616/api/message/myqueue?type=queue
```

fail with this message:

```
only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not m (position: START_DOCUMENT seen m... @1:1)
```

instead using SOAP UI with GET method to consume a message, the server logs this:

```
The clientID header specified is invalid. Client sesion has not yet been established for it: myClientID
```

Anyone has faced the same issue? Could someone explain what is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are sending to port 61616 which is the default OpenWire port which will not work as a REST endpoint.  You need to send them to the correct port which you need to check in your ActiveMQ broker configuration.